# How to calculate the gradient for a custom deep learning layer that takes a 1X1 neuron as input and multiplies it by a constant NXN matrix?

Tags: deep-learning, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I want to create a custom deep learning layer that takes as input a 1X1 neuron and uses it to scale a constant, predefined NXN matrix. I do not understand how to calculate the gradient for this layer.

I understand that in this case dLdZ is NXN and dLdX should be 1X1, and I don't understand what dZdX should be to satisfy that, it's obviously not a simple chained derivative where dLdX = dLdZ*dZdX since the dimensions don't match.

The question is not really language depenedent, I write here in Matlab.
%M is the constant NXN matrix
%X is 1X1X1Xb

```
   Z = zeros(N,N,1,b);
   for i = 1:b
   Z(:,:,:,i) =  squeeze(X(:,:,1,i))*M; 
  end
```

==============================
edit: the answer I got was very helpful. I now perform the calculation as follows:

```
        dLdX = zeros(1,1,1,b);

        for i = 1:b
        dLdX(:,:,:,i) =sum(sum(dLdZ(:,:,:,i).*M)));
        end
```

This works perfectly. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ur question is a little unclear. I will assume ur goal is to propagate the gradients through ur above defined layer to the batch of scalar values. Let me answer according to how I understand it.

U have parameter X, which is a scalar and of dimension b (b: batch_size). This is used to scale a constant matrix Z, which is of dimension NxN. Lets assume u calculate some scalar loss L immediately from the scaled matrix Z' = Z*X, where Z' is of dimension bxNxN.

Then u can calculate the gradients in X according to:

dL/dX = dL/dZ * dZ/dX  --> Note that the dimensions of this product indeed match (unlike ur initial impression) since dL/dZ' is bxNxN and dZ'/dX is bxNxN. Summing over the correct indeces yields dL/dX which is of dimension b.

Did I understand u correct?

Cheers

Comment: Hey, summing over right indexes should be first an element wise multiplication leading to bxNxN of dL/dZ with dZ/dX. Then u contract the each element in the batch by summing over the NxN elements.

Comment: Can u post the modified code which leads to zero gradients?

Comment: I had a very stupid mistype - didn't change the index in the loop. Works perfectly now, thank you!